How to know what to insert in the TO SHIFT in airbus MCDU?
I understand that TO SHIFT is used when departing from an intersection to update the position of the aircraft in the lack of gnss. But how do I know what to put in the TO SHIFT? Is it availabe in the ADC?
Thanks in advance!!

You need training on how to use a manual transmission and clutch to use that feature.

The TO SHIFT is entered either in meters or feet depending on your operators selection of units ([M] or [FT] will displayed next to the field). This image from the FCOM shows an example with 900 m takeoff shift:



(Airbus A320 FCOM - Auto Flight - Flight Management - Takeoff Update)
To figure out the takeoff shift for a given intersection, look at the Takeoff Run Available section on the ground chart. Here is an example for London Stansted (EGSS):

If you want to takeoff from runway 04 at intersection K1 you calculate the difference from rwy head:
$$ \text{TO SHIFT} = 3049 \, \text{m} - 2823 \, \text{m} = 226 \, \text{m} $$

thank you very much! It seems not all aerodromes have this info tho. For example, here in Brazil, at SBGO, we don't have the Takeoff Run Available section on the ground chart (at least, I couldn't find it). So, in situations like this, how do we determine what we have to enter in the TO SHIFT?
I understand it very well seeing that some aerodromes have this info available in the ground charts because you have the info of the TORA of each intersection. But I'm confused on what should I do if I don't have this info availabe.

@Cessna152Driver Sometimes the takeoff run available is on a separate chart, but for SBGO my Jeppesen charts indeed do not include any such section. If these are not officially published and you don't get any official values from your operator, I would reject an intersection takeoff clearance. Remember that intersection takeoffs are always optional.

Some airports might not mention it in the charts, but they will have it displayed on a board near the intersection point of the runway. of course, you can always ask the ATC. And if the ATC wants you to go for an intersection they will explicitly mention the TORA.
In aircraft like an A320, you will use performance software tailored by your operator which will have intersections already in it. If you are using the old charts, they will also be tailored for that. I have done it both ways.

Takeoff shift is the Take off Run Available (TORA) minus take off distance available from the intersection.
For example, if a runway has a TORA of 3400 meters and your intersection take off distance is 2600 meters, takeoff shift will be 800 meters.
